# How to implement rate limiting in laravel based on ip address

Tags: laravel, redis, rate-limiting

I'm currently working on implementing rate limiting using Redis in my Laravel project for an open API that doesn't have authentication. Initially, I attempted to restrict requests to a specific endpoint based on the user's IP address. However, I discovered that different devices on the same network share the same IP address, causing complications.

Are there alternative approaches or methods to address this issue and effectively implement rate limiting in situations where devices on the same network might have identical IP addresses?

Comment: **There is no ways you can identify those devices from a request which is difference but from same ip.**

Comment: You can work around by create an `uuid` as a device_id, and save it in `SESSION`, and rate limiting based on it, while user can easily avoid by clear cookies.